# Oracle - Instant Client

Tags: oracle, odbc, database-installation

I'm trying to install the *Oracle Instant Client* and *ODBC* drivers on a 64 bit, *Windows* 7 machine.

I have downloaded **BOTH**

- Instant Client Package - Basic
- Instant Client Package - ODBC

I had put both sets of files in the same directory:

```
C:\Oracle\instantclient_11_2
```

I set both the `ORACLE_HOME` and `TNS_ADMIN` environment variables to the same directory:

```
C:\Oracle\instantclient_11_2
```

Finally, I am trying to execute the "`odbc_install.exe`" file as an *administrator*.

***ERROR***:  `Oracle ODBC driver with the same name already exists`

The one thing I did **BEFORE** any of this was to install and later uninstall the `OracleXEClient.exe` file.

Not sure how to proceed???

Comment: Did you try a reboot after uninstalling OracleXEClient, since I guess driver uninstall recommends a reboot in Windows.?

Comment: I rebooted several times.

Comment: Did you tried Oracle deinstall utility available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html) ?

Comment: I just installed the entire client.  Worked after that

Answer (score 13):

Open Command Prompt as an Administrator and the run `odbc_install.exe` from there.

Answer (score 3):

Try `odbc_uninstall.exe`. Unfortunatelly, entries may remain in Windows registry. You can search (with `regedit`) for `oracle in instant_client_11_2` or simply `11_2` and delete the corresponding entries for the instant client (take care! not all matches `11_2` are for oracle instant client).

After, execute again `odbc_install.exe`. And additional care if using 32 and 64 bit applications!

Comment: Uninstall wiil remove odbc_install.exe file, so you must have a backup or download ODBC package again.

Answer (score 2):

You may get this message if you didn't run the command prompt or odbc_install.exe as administrator.